# Tree view dropdown using jQuery

Tags: jquery, flask

I have returned though my view the following json response

```
{'pid': ['', 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3], 'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 5, 6], 'name': ['Vehicle', 'Public', 'Private', 'Taxi', 'Bus', 'Micro', 'Car', 'Bike']}
```

Now what i want is the dropdown menu in a treeview manner. can anyone give me some loop idea of how i can achieve that.

the dropdown menu should be something like this

```
Vehicle
  Public
    Taxi
    Bus
    Micro
  Private
    Car
    Bike
```

where each child falls under its respected parent node.

Comment: What kind of visual representation are you trying to achieve? How does the `pid` relates to the position, nesting level/indentation of the item? It is unclear what you're asking right now: perhaps including a diagram or figure or what you want will help.

Comment: pid is the parent id value of each nodes which defines if its a root node or a child node or subchild of a node etc

Comment: Just a suggestion, return you data like this: `{'Vehicle': {'Public' : {1: 'taxi', 2: 'bus'}, 'Private': {3: 'bike', 4: 'car'}}}`. It will be really easy to loop over it in js, as compared to your own answer.

Comment: okie thank you mate i am new and still learning :) @Joost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, I got what I needed:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#group_id").click(function () {
            if ($('#group_id').val() === '') {
                $.getJSON(
                    '/group',
                    function (data) {
                        $('#group_id').find('option').remove();
                        var len = data.id.length;
                        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                            if (data.pid[i] === '') {
                                var root_item = '<option value="' + data.id[i] + '">' + data.name[i] + "</option>";
                                $('#group_id').append(root_item);
                                for (var j = 0; j < len; j++) {
                                    if (data.pid[j] === data.id[i]) {
                                        var child_item = '<option value="' + data.id[j] + '">' + '&nbsp' + data.name[j] + "</option>";
                                        $('#group_id').append(child_item);
                                        for (var k = 0; k < len; k++) {
                                            if (data.pid[k] === data.id[j]) {
                                                var subchild_item = '<option value="' + data.id[k] + '">' + '&nbsp&nbsp' + data.name[k] + "</option>";
                                                $('#group_id').append(subchild_item);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```